# How to make Tinder like Bio editor - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want a Tinder-like Bio editor, When the user taps on the info, the text field should appear and retrieve the data from the firebase, and display the old bio, if the user taps on the done button on the keyboard or press anywhere on the screen, the data should be submitted. Thanking you in advance

Update: Here is the code I tried, Is there any way I can remove the upper stack and show the text field when the about container is tapped and after the submission the stack to come back and display the about field, and also I want to retrieve the old text from firebase in the text field(when the user is updating).

```
Widget about(BuildContext context, dynamic snapshot) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
  child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height * 0.2,
        width: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: constantColors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 8.0,
                  left: 10,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "About",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, left: 6),
                child: Icon(
                  FontAwesome.pencil,
                  size: 13,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [

              Container(
                height: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .height * 0.1,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width,
                child: TextField(
                  onTap: (){
                    Provider.of<PostFunctions>(context, listen: false).about(context, Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false).getUserUid, {
                      'about': aboutController.text,
                    });
                  },
                  controller: aboutController,
                  maxLines: 8,
                  cursorColor: constantColors.green,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      hintText: 'A little about you',
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      fillColor: constantColors.white,
                      filled: true,),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .height * 0.1,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width,
                color: constantColors.white,
                child: Text(snapshot.data.data()['about']),),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),



);
```

}

here is the future method of uploading and updating

```
Future about(BuildContext context, String userID, dynamic data)async{
return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).update(data);
```

}

Comment: Attach a [repro] of what you have tried so far, and the problems you had: read [ask].

Comment: Are you having errors when making that process? If so, could you provide information on the issue/error and what you did so far?

Comment: @padaleiana Sorry, I am not active, I updated the code I tried.

Comment: @Eduardo Yes, when I TAP on the container, the text field is not opening, I am new to flutter, If you could explain me in more brief, I will be thankful

Answer (score 0):

The better approach will be to retrieve the user data ahead of time. Then you can populate the text field using its [conntroller](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) with the data if the data exists.